# How is this email message encoded?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encoding

I received spam email that looks like this in `Outlook 2016` desktop application on Windows 7 and in Outlook web app:

```
Dvtmenj1s7wbqaru8daz Siwqmbg56gr,

Are[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0] SeNJfYSy[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]oIEqxPdu [RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]loc6ok[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]ingHTM4A faydDTBor qv32g0ldlowm1ztrug pRuhYZcTricyxaes [RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]ongq6ypqhq MRGnRnLo[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]uldho & xawhco8hePla9yVBIsttadm7p6hpic [RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]proshobwmr2dKqoN6uc[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]tmmmf51ais ps9xvlrwi[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]t[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]h xvlbs6xgre[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]at p[RAND_LETTER-1UP_0]rp2tgwkcg1odPDjpucagkuwdt
...
```

If I look at it on Android phone default mail app it looks like this:

```
Dear sir,
Are you looking for low prices on Mould & Plastic products with great product quality?
You found the BEST!
...
```

If I copy the text from mail app and paste it anywhere the pasted text is again in the unreadable form.

I looked at headers of this mail but didn't find anything out of ordinary there.

What encoding system is this?

EDIT:

Here is hex output of the message:

```
00000000: 4672 6f6d 3a09 3020 3c73 656e 6465 723e  From:.0 <sender>
00000010: 0d0a 5365 6e74 3a09 362e 2041 7072 696c  ..Sent:.6. April
00000020: 2032 3031 3920 3138 3a34 390d 0a54 6f3a   2019 18:49..To:
00000030: 093c 7265 6369 7069 656e 743e 0d0a 5375  .<recipient>..Su
00000040: 626a 6563 743a 0944 482d 3032 3035 372d  bject:.DH-02057-
00000050: 3030 3739 0d0a 0d0a 4476 746d 656e 6a31  0079....Dvtmenj1
00000060: 7337 7762 7161 7275 3864 617a 2053 6977  s7wbqaru8daz Siw
00000070: 716d 6267 3536 6772 2c0d 0a20 0d0a 4172  qmbg56gr,.. ..Ar
00000080: 655b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155  e[RAND_LETTER-1U
00000090: 505f 305d 2053 654e 4a66 5953 795b 5241  P_0] SeNJfYSy[RA
000000a0: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
000000b0: 6f49 4571 7850 6475 200d 0a5b 5241 4e44  oIEqxPdu ..[RAND
000000c0: 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6c6f  _LETTER-1UP_0]lo
000000d0: 6336 6f6b 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  c6ok[RAND_LETTER
000000e0: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d69 6e67 4854 4d34 4120  -1UP_0]ingHTM4A
000000f0: 6661 7964 4454 426f 7220 0d0a 7176 3332  faydDTBor ..qv32
00000100: 6730 6c64 6c6f 776d 317a 7472 7567 2070  g0ldlowm1ztrug p
00000110: 5275 6859 5a63 5472 6963 7978 6165 7320  RuhYZcTricyxaes
00000120: 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550  [RAND_LETTER-1UP
00000130: 5f30 5d6f 6e67 7136 7970 7168 7120 0d0a  _0]ongq6ypqhq ..
00000140: 4d52 476e 526e 4c6f 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  MRGnRnLo[RAND_LE
00000150: 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d75 6c64 686f  TTER-1UP_0]uldho
00000160: 2026 2078 6177 6863 6f38 6865 506c 6139   & xawhco8hePla9
00000170: 7956 4249 7374 7461 646d 3770 3668 7069  yVBIsttadm7p6hpi
00000180: 6320 0d0a 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  c ..[RAND_LETTER
00000190: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d70 726f 7368 6f62 776d  -1UP_0]proshobwm
000001a0: 7232 644b 716f 4e36 7563 5b52 414e 445f  r2dKqoN6uc[RAND_
000001b0: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d74 6d6d  LETTER-1UP_0]tmm
000001c0: 6d66 3531 6169 7320 0d0a 7073 3978 766c  mf51ais ..ps9xvl
000001d0: 7277 695b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  rwi[RAND_LETTER-
000001e0: 3155 505f 305d 745b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  1UP_0]t[RAND_LET
000001f0: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6820 7876 6c62  TER-1UP_0]h xvlb
00000200: 7336 7867 7265 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454  s6xgre[RAND_LETT
00000210: 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d61 7420 705b  ER-..1UP_0]at p[
00000220: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f  RAND_LETTER-1UP_
00000230: 305d 7270 3274 6777 6b63 6731 6f64 5044  0]rp2tgwkcg1odPD
00000240: 6a70 7563 6167 6b75 7764 7420 0d0a 5337  jpucagkuwdt ..S7
00000250: 4a46 654c 7175 6f77 746c 3568 647a 6261  JFeLquowtl5hdzba
00000260: 6c38 7341 4b5a 3232 7979 3669 745b 5241  l8sAKZ22yy6it[RA
00000270: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000280: 793f 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31  y?[RAND_LETTER-1
00000290: 5550 5f30 5d20 0d0a 596f 5b52 414e 445f  UP_0] ..Yo[RAND_
000002a0: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d75 2039  LETTER-1UP_0]u 9
000002b0: 386c 6b66 6f6a 6734 6d6e 7274 6675 7a75  8lkfojg4mnrtfuzu
000002c0: 6e4e 6530 636b 645b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  nNe0ckd[RAND_LET
000002d0: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 200d 0a4e 7233  TER-1UP_0] ..Nr3
000002e0: 4370 424c 5574 685b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  CpBLUth[RAND_LET
000002f0: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6520 6178 3763  TER-1UP_0]e ax7c
00000300: 386e 4245 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  8nBE[RAND_LETTER
00000310: 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d53 5b52 414e 445f  -..1UP_0]S[RAND_
00000320: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d54 4c58  LETTER-1UP_0]TLX
00000330: 5821 2120 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  X!! [RAND_LETTER
00000340: 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d6a 6f61 6a69 474e  -..1UP_0]joajiGN
00000350: 6934 7262 6b77 615b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  i4rbkwa[RAND_LET
00000360: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 2069 7361 706e  TER-1UP_0] isapn
00000370: 3665 6b78 776d 6f20 6641 7468 655b 5241  6ekxwmo fAthe[RA
00000380: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f  ND_LETTER-..1UP_
00000390: 305d 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  0] [RAND_LETTER-
000003a0: 3155 505f 305d 6f72 695b 5241 4e44 5f4c  1UP_0]ori[RAND_L
000003b0: 4554 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f 305d 6769  ETTER-..1UP_0]gi
000003c0: 6e61 317a 3234 3265 6c61 5b52 414e 445f  na1z242ela[RAND_
000003d0: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d6c 5b52  LETTER-1UP_0]l[R
000003e0: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30  AND_LETTER-1UP_0
000003f0: 5d20 0d0a 7562 6c72 7538 7239 786f 616a  ] ..ublru8r9xoaj
00000400: 3978 6f6a 7577 6e64 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  9xojuwnd[RAND_LE
00000410: 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d20 745b 5241  TTER-1UP_0] t[RA
00000420: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000430: 6864 6c43 6564 6520 0d0a 6d5b 5241 4e44  hdlCede ..m[RAND
00000440: 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6f73  _LETTER-1UP_0]os
00000450: 745b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155  t[RAND_LETTER-1U
00000460: 505f 305d 204c 5846 6b6c 6e74 7277 6167  P_0] LXFklntrwag
00000470: 4c49 3075 7374 7933 794b 6561 796b 7364  LI0usty3yKeayksd
00000480: 200d 0a6d 6936 7165 7474 616e 755b 5241   ..mi6qettanu[RA
00000490: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
000004a0: 6661 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31  fa[RAND_LETTER-1
000004b0: 5550 5f30 5d63 7475 7534 6672 7265 5b52  UP_0]ctuu4frre[R
000004c0: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550  AND_LETTER-..1UP
000004d0: 5f30 5d72 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445  _0]r [RAND_LETTE
000004e0: 522d 3155 505f 305d 666f 6e72 3776 7261  R-1UP_0]fonr7vra
000004f0: 6368 6920 4d6f 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454  chi Mo[RAND_LETT
00000500: 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d75 5b52 414e  ER-..1UP_0]u[RAN
00000510: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d6c  D_LETTER-1UP_0]l
00000520: 6420 2620 5072 6a36 6565 7078 6c79 3361  d & Prj6eepxly3a
00000530: 616d 616e 7273 7465 674f 534e 6963 5b52  amanrstegOSNic[R
00000540: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550  AND_LETTER-..1UP
00000550: 5f30 5d20 7075 306c 6c30 726f 6c4e 4247  _0] pu0ll0rolNBG
00000560: 6475 6275 7965 6878 7966 6763 7450 5935  dubuyehxyfgctPY5
00000570: 4d73 2e20 0d0a 5072 4f75 3638 6f64 7573  Ms. ..PrOu68odus
00000580: 4663 7420 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  Fct [RAND_LETTER
00000590: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d43 6167 6e73 776f 6d76  -1UP_0]Cagnswomv
000005a0: 7446 675a 3965 7732 5756 7665 676f 5b52  tFgZ9ew2WVvego[R
000005b0: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550  AND_LETTER-..1UP
000005c0: 5f30 5d72 6965 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454  _0]rie[RAND_LETT
000005d0: 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d73 3a20 0d0a 3129  ER-1UP_0]s: ..1)
000005e0: 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550  [RAND_LETTER-1UP
000005f0: 5f30 5d20 4175 5252 4839 4755 7464 3263  _0] AuRRH9GUtd2c
00000600: 7463 7568 3775 316f 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  tcuh7u1o[RAND_LE
00000610: 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d6d 6f74  TTER-..1UP_0]mot
00000620: 3768 7962 7864 6976 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  7hybxdiv[RAND_LE
00000630: 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d65 3858 3875  TTER-1UP_0]e8X8u
00000640: 6f39 7220 7061 7377 7170 6676 726f 6461  o9r paswqpfvroda
00000650: 6f69 7563 3538 4643 6274 7367 6b33 3564  oiuc58FCbtsgk35d
00000660: 6f68 200d 0a3a 5176 4e4b 205b 5241 4e44  oh ..:QvNK [RAND
00000670: 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 5468  _LETTER-1UP_0]Th
00000680: 7870 6778 6765 735b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  xpgxges[RAND_LET
00000690: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6520 6175 7831  TER-1UP_0]e aux1
000006a0: 6a34 7272 6520 0d0a 3733 6263 7631 6578  j4rre ..73bcv1ex
000006b0: 7974 685b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  yth[RAND_LETTER-
000006c0: 3155 505f 305d 6520 636c 6c34 757a 6733  1UP_0]e cll4uzg3
000006d0: 6831 3072 4430 4e46 655b 5241 4e44 5f4c  h10rD0NFe[RAND_L
000006e0: 4554 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f 305d 6170  ETTER-..1UP_0]ap
000006f0: 6536 6e41 6a78 6741 485a 7374 205b 5241  e6nAjxgAHZst [RA
00000700: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000710: 616e 3269 7536 3864 3765 617a 7078 3842  an2iu68d7eazpx8B
00000720: 7520 6265 6869 6d73 7471 6435 5a42 5652  u behimstqd5ZBVR
00000730: 200d 0a70 725b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445   ..pr[RAND_LETTE
00000740: 522d 3155 505f 305d 6f64 5146 3354 4948  R-1UP_0]odQF3TIH
00000750: 626d 4a75 6364 6c6b 6a67 7473 6376 4173  bmJucdlkjgtscvAs
00000760: 376d 2079 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  7m y[RAND_LETTER
00000770: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d6f 7520 0d0a 5b52 414e  -1UP_0]ou ..[RAN
00000780: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d77  D_LETTER-1UP_0]w
00000790: 695b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155  i[RAND_LETTER-1U
000007a0: 505f 305d 6c63 4764 4a47 6c45 7278 6d66  P_0]lcGdJGlErxmf
000007b0: 7648 356d 200d 0a66 646f 7365 6b6b 706e  vH5m ..fdosekkpn
000007c0: 696e 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31  in[RAND_LETTER-1
000007d0: 5550 5f30 5d64 4145 7762 7272 4c20 6f6e  UP_0]dAEwbrrL on
000007e0: 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550  [RAND_LETTER-1UP
000007f0: 5f30 5d20 0d0a 7468 316d 516d 7765 5b52  _0] ..th1mQmwe[R
00000800: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30  AND_LETTER-1UP_0
00000810: 5d20 3567 6b69 6e63 7438 6269 7465 5662  ] 5gkinct8biteVb
00000820: 5838 726e 6568 725a 4937 3458 7269 7421  X8rnehrZI74Xrit!
00000830: 200d 0a32 6e77 6c67 334b 346a 474d 2920   ..2nwlg3K4jGM)
00000840: 6164 4947 6242 6b79 456c 5b52 414e 445f  adIGbBkyEl[RAND_
00000850: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d65 635b  LETTER-1UP_0]ec[
00000860: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 0d0a 3155  RAND_LETTER-..1U
00000870: 505f 305d 745b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445  P_0]t[RAND_LETTE
00000880: 522d 3155 505f 305d 7269 6368 7573 6e73  R-1UP_0]richusns
00000890: 6166 7320 656a 7072 6f62 3334 6f64 755b  afs ejprob34odu[
000008a0: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 0d0a 3155  RAND_LETTER-..1U
000008b0: 505f 305d 6374 6b78 7568 6d6c 7076 733a  P_0]ctkxuhmlpvs:
000008c0: 706a 4c52 4e78 3420 5445 4168 6566 6e77  pjLRNx4 TEAhefnw
000008d0: 6679 786d 7473 6520 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  fyxmtse [RAND_LE
000008e0: 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d45 6c41  TTER-..1UP_0]ElA
000008f0: 6b65 6370 7167 7078 7430 7474 7a79 7335  kecpqgpxt0ttzys5
00000900: 6d32 7072 614d 6135 4879 6976 4831 6f77  m2praMa5HyivH1ow
00000910: 674a 3076 5763 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  gJ0vWc [RAND_LET
00000920: 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f 305d 7065 7348  TER-..1UP_0]pesH
00000930: 4979 6336 4672 6f5b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  Iyc6Fro[RAND_LET
00000940: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6475 3775 6f6d  TER-1UP_0]du7uom
00000950: 7663 635b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  vcc[RAND_LETTER-
00000960: 3155 505f 305d 7473 3a64 6f66 6e64 6d20  1UP_0]ts:dofndm
00000970: 0d0a 616c 7a68 7265 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c  ..alzhre [RAND_L
00000980: 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 616c 6c72  ETTER-1UP_0]allr
00000990: 6b79 786d 6a20 7476 756c 7064 7265 616a  kyxmj tvulpdreaj
000009a0: 6879 7a6b 7771 6479 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c  hyzkwqdy [RAND_L
000009b0: 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 746f 200d  ETTER-1UP_0]to .
000009c0: 0a75 735b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  .us[RAND_LETTER-
000009d0: 3155 505f 305d 6520 695b 5241 4e44 5f4c  1UP_0]e i[RAND_L
000009e0: 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6e20 774c  ETTER-1UP_0]n wL
000009f0: 346f 7677 4a4d 6572 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  4ovwJMer[RAND_LE
00000a00: 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d6c 6462  TTER-..1UP_0]ldb
00000a10: 4444 5052 5149 7769 6837 6465 200d 0a33  DDPRQIwih7de ..3
00000a20: 686e 6968 7178 2920 7578 765a 7774 6f66  hnihqx) uxvZwtof
00000a30: 5954 6548 5775 4933 5a78 346c 655b 5241  YTeHWuI3Zx4le[RA
00000a40: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000a50: 635b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 0d0a  c[RAND_LETTER-..
00000a60: 3155 505f 305d 6f5b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  1UP_0]o[RAND_LET
00000a70: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6d6d 6f71 756e  TER-1UP_0]mmoqun
00000a80: 4a39 4766 3274 3965 6976 3776 5a46 7857  J9Gf2t9eiv7vZFxW
00000a90: 6876 6c63 6174 746c 6f32 6769 6f42 6a4a  hvlcattlo2gioBjJ
00000aa0: 5441 7153 6e32 6e20 0d0a 3147 3254 5936  TAqSn2n ..1G2TY6
00000ab0: 7072 6f67 7173 6475 6a70 7a74 6832 7179  progqsdujpzth2qy
00000ac0: 6374 3038 7135 6934 6651 3173 7574 6571  ct08q5i4fQ1suteq
00000ad0: 396c 676d 3a20 5476 6e64 6865 5b52 414e  9lgm: Tvndhe[RAN
00000ae0: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d79  D_LETTER-1UP_0]y
00000af0: 200d 0a61 7a62 3675 384d 7265 3668 6550   ..azb6u8Mre6heP
00000b00: 4a20 7653 6b57 3565 7262 6636 7932 3270  J vSkW5erbf6y22p
00000b10: 6832 206c 6f5b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445  h2 lo[RAND_LETTE
00000b20: 522d 3155 505f 305d 772d 0d0a 4e34 6b68  R-1UP_0]w-..N4kh
00000b30: 6870 726a 6176 6168 616a 6469 6365 5b52  hprjavahajdice[R
00000b40: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30  AND_LETTER-1UP_0
00000b50: 5d64 2077 6867 7867 7565 6976 7577 696c  ]d whgxgueivuwil
00000b60: 6531 3475 2073 746d 5079 4936 6c35 5269  e14u stmPyI6l5Ri
00000b70: 6c6c 6475 6d62 6673 3270 6c20 0d0a 5b52  lldumbfs2pl ..[R
00000b80: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30  AND_LETTER-1UP_0
00000b90: 5d68 6176 7a6f 6f30 6e71 366d 6969 6e67  ]havzoo0nq6miing
00000ba0: 706c 6c77 7768 756a 6b20 6772 7a72 776b  pllwwhujk grzrwk
00000bb0: 3969 306a 7265 615b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  9i0jrea[RAND_LET
00000bc0: 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f 305d 7420 687a  TER-..1UP_0]t hz
00000bd0: 6c6c 4b34 3359 6465 6730 6673 696b 7165  llK43Ydeg0fsikqe
00000be0: 7467 6e20 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  tgn [RAND_LETTER
00000bf0: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d61 6e64 5b52 414e 445f  -1UP_0]and[RAND_
00000c00: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d20 0d0a  LETTER-1UP_0] ..
00000c10: 706b 6f65 6f65 725b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  pkoeoer[RAND_LET
00000c20: 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 666f 725b 5241  TER-1UP_0]for[RA
00000c30: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000c40: 6d61 736c 7966 6e63 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  maslyfnc[RAND_LE
00000c50: 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d65 396b  TTER-..1UP_0]e9k
00000c60: 6d72 6268 736a 672e 200d 0a34 6361 6f72  mrbhsjg. ..4caor
00000c70: 3965 6f33 7729 2047 6f6d 3573 4d65 6e30  9eo3w) Gom5sMen0
00000c80: 3135 6364 6975 6c7a 6b6e 3939 6361 4347  15cdiulzkn99caCG
00000c90: 6656 5952 456c 200d 0a70 7633 316c 6b72  fVYREl ..pv31lkr
00000ca0: 726f 6446 3577 4736 7952 6475 5b52 414e  rodF5wG6yRdu[RAN
00000cb0: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d63  D_LETTER-1UP_0]c
00000cc0: 6d68 6a62 6768 6274 733a 5b52 414e 445f  mhjbghbts:[RAND_
00000cd0: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d20 0d0a  LETTER-1UP_0] ..
00000ce0: 534d 4e73 6c77 6974 7663 7271 6820 6d5b  SMNslwitvcrqh m[
00000cf0: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f  RAND_LETTER-1UP_
00000d00: 305d 616e 4952 6f79 206b 5557 5462 6e31  0]anIRoy kUWTbn1
00000d10: 6b58 696e 3769 7039 6279 6473 6e70 3168  kXin7ip9bydsnp1h
00000d20: 6a76 200d 0a61 3671 7966 7061 7369 6e64  jv ..a6qyfpasind
00000d30: 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550  [RAND_LETTER-1UP
00000d40: 5f30 5d20 676b 6a74 7a67 6a75 6a6f 664f  _0] gkjtzgjujofO
00000d50: 6f69 6377 6470 3430 516c 5a44 2071 5b52  oicwdp40QlZD q[R
00000d60: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550  AND_LETTER-..1UP
00000d70: 5f30 5d75 6161 6a72 6c69 5343 674e 6b67  _0]uaajrliSCgNkg
00000d80: 5947 3674 6d54 790d 0a20 0d0a 495b 5241  YG6tmTy.. ..I[RA
00000d90: 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d  ND_LETTER-1UP_0]
00000da0: 6666 6271 6962 6d66 6a74 6d20 6964 7161  ffbqibmfjtm idqa
00000db0: 3674 6772 746e 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454  6tgrtn[RAND_LETT
00000dc0: 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d74 7a75 6330  ER-..1UP_0]tzuc0
00000dd0: 6572 655b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  ere[RAND_LETTER-
00000de0: 3155 505f 305d 7354 4368 486b 3474 7276  1UP_0]sTChHk4trv
00000df0: 4e65 645b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  Ned[RAND_LETTER-
00000e00: 3155 505f 305d 200d 0a76 7662 7074 645b  1UP_0] ..vvbptd[
00000e10: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f  RAND_LETTER-1UP_
00000e20: 305d 6f5b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  0]o[RAND_LETTER-
00000e30: 3155 505f 305d 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554  1UP_0] [RAND_LET
00000e40: 5445 522d 0d0a 3155 505f 305d 6765 747a  TER-..1UP_0]getz
00000e50: 4544 3120 6277 706b 7247 5064 6163 4830  ED1 bwpkrGPdacH0
00000e60: 6544 5970 326b 2058 5766 614e 694f 7174  eDYp2k XWfaNiOqt
00000e70: 6f44 5749 3972 7141 206d 397a 7364 3465  oDWI9rqA m9zsd4e
00000e80: 2076 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d   v[RAND_LETTER-.
00000e90: 0a31 5550 5f30 5d69 616b 6f6c 6e38 316b  .1UP_0]iakoln81k
00000ea0: 676c 206d 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  gl m[RAND_LETTER
00000eb0: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d79 204f 5139 7265 6d61  -1UP_0]y OQ9rema
00000ec0: 6575 7333 6e78 7772 6669 6c72 6f69 7562  eus3nxwrfilroiub
00000ed0: 7a2e 0d0a 4266 6262 7a63 776e 7165 7374  z...Bfbbzcwnqest
00000ee0: 7357 4920 7265 7551 3941 5136 4c30 595a  sWI reuQ9AQ6L0YZ
00000ef0: 6761 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d  ga[RAND_LETTER-.
00000f00: 0a31 5550 5f30 5d72 4b51 5933 7a35 6970  .1UP_0]rKQY3z5ip
00000f10: 7a64 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31  zd[RAND_LETTER-1
00000f20: 5550 5f30 5d73 2c0d 0a42 695b 5241 4e44  UP_0]s,..Bi[RAND
00000f30: 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6c6c  _LETTER-1UP_0]ll
00000f40: 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550  [RAND_LETTER-1UP
00000f50: 5f30 5d69 650d 0a20 0d0a 2d49 2747 534e  _0]ie.. ..-I'GSN
00000f60: 3163 7569 6c6c 2076 777a 6a67 6935 706c  1cuill vwzjgi5pl
00000f70: 7878 7665 6a74 6f70 2056 6c37 4262 795b  xxvejtop Vl7Bby[
00000f80: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f  RAND_LETTER-1UP_
00000f90: 305d 6f75 6b74 7061 7462 200d 0a6d 795b  0]ouktpatb ..my[
00000fa0: 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f  RAND_LETTER-1UP_
00000fb0: 305d 2063 5854 496f 5b52 414e 445f 4c45  0] cXTIo[RAND_LE
00000fc0: 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d6e 5b52 414e  TTER-1UP_0]n[RAN
00000fd0: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30  D_LETTER-..1UP_0
00000fe0: 5d74 6163 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  ]tac[RAND_LETTER
00000ff0: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d74 6b74 7364 6c6a 7579  -1UP_0]tktsdljuy
00001000: 6720 6438 7169 5964 7865 7461 5b52 414e  g d8qiYdxeta[RAN
00001010: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30  D_LETTER-..1UP_0
00001020: 5d69 6c5b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d  ]il[RAND_LETTER-
00001030: 3155 505f 305d 7368 6862 7a63 7562 2061  1UP_0]shhbzcub a
00001040: 6e62 3634 6420 5447 5674 5248 5353 634b  nb64d TGVtRHSScK
00001050: 6f74 4238 4476 4c6b 3168 6549 4275 6772  otB8DvLk1heIBugr
00001060: 7220 0d0a 6966 6c72 6837 6b6d 706f 3065  r ..iflrh7kmpo0e
00001070: 7245 7274 316b 6879 7761 616e 5b52 414e  rErt1khywaan[RAN
00001080: 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d74  D_LETTER-1UP_0]t
00001090: 2069 756f 7578 7670 6e66 6f66 6968 7175   iuouxvpnfofihqu
000010a0: 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 0d0a   [RAND_LETTER-..
000010b0: 3155 505f 305d 7570 6f7a 396c 4c68 796e  1UP_0]upoz9lLhyn
000010c0: 205b 5241 4e44 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155   [RAND_LETTER-1U
000010d0: 505f 305d 796e 546f 7574 7a7a 6576 7964  P_0]ynToutzzevyd
000010e0: 6872 626c 6a55 4a20 6276 7962 7265 5b52  hrbljUJ bvybre[R
000010f0: 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550  AND_LETTER-..1UP
00001100: 5f30 5d74 7572 7266 6872 346f 6f6e 2063  _0]turrfhr4oon c
00001110: 3964 4a63 7769 4b50 4b63 6f5b 5241 4e44  9dJcwiKPKco[RAND
00001120: 5f4c 4554 5445 522d 3155 505f 305d 6e74  _LETTER-1UP_0]nt
00001130: 6158 3556 6374 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454  aX5Vct[RAND_LETT
00001140: 4552 2d0d 0a31 5550 5f30 5d2e 2055 4e78  ER-..1UP_0]. UNx
00001150: 686f 6754 5b52 414e 445f 4c45 5454 4552  hogT[RAND_LETTER
00001160: 2d31 5550 5f30 5d68 616e 5b52 414e 445f  -1UP_0]han[RAND_
00001170: 4c45 5454 4552 2d31 5550 5f30 5d6b 2059  LETTER-1UP_0]k Y
00001180: 627a 6763 6f75 2e0d 0a20 0d0a 200d 0a20  bzgcou... .. ..
00001190: 0d0a                                     ..
```

Comment: Perhaps you could save the message as a file, and inspect it in a hex editor? BTW I found the same message here (https://messages.millerelec.com/2018/12/25/dt-02131-0003850/), and when you inspect it using the browser's developer tools, you will find that it is an HTML message, where many characters are moved off-screen by using CSS such as *position: absolute; top: -5894px; left: -7914px;*. It seems  to me that some email clients support this, while others don't. If you copy+paste the text from that page, you will get the garbled version.

Comment: @Berend your comments seems like a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like trying to bypass spamfilter by sending message that looks scrambled and is only put together by css. When you try to copy the message you copy the data outside the view.